# Track file access during a cmake build

Tags: build, cmake, build-system

Some build systems ([e.g. tup](http://gittup.org/tup/ex_dependencies.html)) can track file accesses during a build. This enables them to find errors in the build config. For example, if a file is read but not specified as a dependency.

Now I already have a complicated CMake build configuration. Is there a tool or trick to do such file access tracking during a build with Cmake?

Comment: "... during a build with Cmake" - It is not CMake who drivers the *build*. Instead, it is performed by a build system - Makefile, Visual Studio, Ninja, and so on. If you use only `add_executable` or `add_library` command, you may be confident that all file-dependencies are correct. If you use `add_custom_command` (or macro/function which wrap it), you specify plain command line for it: program with parameters. And CMake cannot determine, which parameter denotes accessed file.

Comment: Correct, CMake cannot determine accessed files. However, in theory there could be tooling to track accessed files dynamically. For example, tup can do it (see my link above). Afaik GNU Make and Ninja cannot do that. Maybe some other build backend of CMake? Maybe there is some commercial tooling?

Comment: In other words, you ask for a build system which supports file access tracking and can be used as a backend for CMake. This looks like a **software recomendation** question, and Stack Overflow isn't a good place for such questions. You are better ask on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: I found this thread for ninja: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ninja-build/JSAPqWa5kmA This means I could try to use CMakes Ninja backend together with one of the two scripts there.